# How to change the height of address bar (where is the path of a dirct./file) on Double Commander?

Tags: xubuntu, configuration, gtk, doublecmd

Is it possible to change the height of address bar on Double Commander?

OS: Xubuntu 16.04.5 Appreciate some help, Vladi.

[image: address bar double commander]

Comment: I found it settings>fonts>increase height of a font

Comment: You can add that as answer :)